# How can I get the invoicing and shipping profiles for a user?

Tags: 8, commerce

How can I get two separate profiles, one for shipping and one for invoicing? I can get the default profile for a user, but there does not appear to a type associated with it.

In Drupal 7 I could use commerce_addressbook_get_default_profile_id to get the default profile per type, but I don't see this function or an equivalent in Commerce 2.

I'm porting a custom module from a Drupal 7 online shop to a Drupal 8 online shop. This custom module synchronizes user and order data to Navision which has separate fields for shipping and invoicing.
Ideally I'd also be able to use hook_profile_update to sync the profile updates to Navision.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this in a roundabout way:

- Get the most recent order for the user
- Get the shipping and billing profile for this order

If there are no orders, the user's unlikely to have shipping and billing info